# Good way to prevent student from messing program settings in /home/user

Tags: permissions, home, dot-files

I am a teacher and I use Linux which is great! But students are curious about this "new" operating system they do not know and in GUI they tweak program settings which affects hidden files inside `/home/user`:

```
[profesor@240-kateder ~]$ ls -a
.              .dbeaver4         .gtkrc-2.0        .sane
..             .dbeaver-drivers  .icons            .swt
.bash_history  .dropbox          .kde4             .themes
.bash_logout   .eclipse          .local            .thumbnails
.bash_profile  .esd_auth         .lyx              .ViberPC
.bashrc        .FlatCAM          .masterpdfeditor  .w3m
.cache         .FreeCAD          .mozilla          .Xauthority
.config        .gimp-2.8         .pki              .xinitrc
.convertall    .gnupg            .qucs             .xournal
```

This is unwanted because over time program interfaces will change so dramatically that programs will be missing toolbars, buttons, main menus, status menus... and students end up with completely different GUI, so they are calling me about the issue and we spend too much time.

Now to optimize this I have to make sure that program settings (hidden files inside `/home/user`) aren't changed, so I tried to change them like `sudo chmod -R 555 ~/.*` but this didn't work out well for all of the programs, because some of the programs want to manipulate their settings at boot and they therefore fail to start withouth `sudo`. And student's don't have `sudo` privileges.

But `sudo chmod -R 555 ~/.*` worked for `.bash_profile`, `.bash_logout`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_history`, `.xinitrc` so I was thinking if I would:

1. prevent user from deleting `.bash_profile`, `.bash_logout`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_history`, `.xinitrc`
2. copy all hidden setting files into a folder `/opt/restore_settings`
3. program `.bash_profile` to clean up all settings in users home directory on login using `rm -r ~/.*` (I assume this wouldn't delete files from point 1., if I protect them) and then restore settings from the `/opt/restore_settings`.

I wan't to know your opinion about this idea, or if there is any better way to do it. And I need a way to prevent users from deleting files from point 1. Otherwise this can't work.

Comment: My personal opinion would be to instead provide hourly, daily and weekly backups of their home directories accessible through `~/.snapshots/` using something like `rsnapshot`. That way they can restore files if they need to. I'm not a big fan of locking people down... especially students.

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't like locking them down too, but as I said if you want to work in a didactical way locking them down is needed. Otherwise after a month of usage, newly installed operating systems will be all messed up.

Comment: I believe that making mistakes is part of the learning  process. So allow your students to make them, but do guide them to overcome such mistakes.

Comment: Let them make mistakes at home. In school I have to keep 120 computers keep on running and I really don't have nerves to run from one computer to another to reset the program settings...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Totally different approach: Create a group `students`, give each student his own account with group membership in `students`. Have a script that restores a given home directory from a template to a known good state, possibly deleting all extra dot files. Tell students about this script.

If you have a number of computers, centralize this approach (user management on a single central server), and use a central file server for student home directories, so each student gets the same home directory on any machine.

Together with proper (basic `chmod`) permissions everywhere, this will ensure that each student can only wreak havoc in his or her own home directoy, and can restore it when it breaks, possibly loosing their own customizations in this process, so they'll be more cautious next time.

BTW, that's a very standard setup for many users on a cluster of machines.

Comment: This is very similar to the approach I suggested. Well anyway I did it the way I suggested and it works nicely! Because you also gave idea about central server I will accept your answer as the best one.

Answer (score 4):

Setting `Immutable` and `Undeletable` attributes on the dotfiles via `chattr` should help. See `man chattr` or [the wikipedia entry for chattr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattr)

Does not prevent changing or deleting totally since a user can run `chattr`, but it makes it definitely more obscure.

Comment: I think making it more obscure will do! =)

Comment: This does not solve the problem that the applications want to legitimately change and save their settings at startup.

Comment: True for newly created files .. but not true for existing of pre-created files like `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` or `.anything`, as stated.

Comment: This doesn't work well, because it locks some files and X cannot start on relogin. So it looks like locking files isn't even an option...